# How much do a DC-9's wings weigh?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, dc-9-family

How much do the wings weigh?  How much does the landing gear weigh? How much fuel does it take to fill the tanks? We, at Confederation College are trying to donate a DC-9 for training purposes and require information to facilitate this.

Comment: Have you tried searching for any of this information?  What did you find?

Comment: @dalearn I reckon it is a valid question. Data of weights of parts of structures is not easy to find, especially not of a type manufactured in the pre-search-engine days.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/67323), for the DC9-10 variant:

- the wing group weighs 9470 lbs
- the landing gear weighs 3660 lbs

Wikipedia mentions the fuel weight as 24,743 lbs.

For other variants, scale the wing and landing gear weights up with the ratio of Empty Weights found on Wikipedia.